# Create vue layout in laravel ui

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I use Laravel 8 with laravel/ui 3.4 for front end.
I want to create fixed sidebar, footer and an area for router-view.

routes/web.php

```
Route::view('/{any}', 'home')->where('any', '.*');
```

resources/home.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view />
    </div>    
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

resouces/js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap')

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from './router'

createApp({}).use(router).mount('#app')
```

resouces/js/router/index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'    
import Shop from '../pages/Shop'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'shop',
        component: Shop
    }
]    
export default createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})
```

resouces/js/components/Sidebar.vue

```
<template>
This is fixed sidebar. This includes dynamics content
</template>
```

How to include this sidebar in home.blade.php ?
Or is there any way to create default Vue layout with child components?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I create a sidebar at `js/components/layouts/MainSidebar.vue`

js/app.js

```
import mainsidebar from './components/layouts/MainSidebar.vue'
const app = createApp({})
app.component('main-sidebar', MainSidebar)
```

home.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
    <main-sidebar></main-sidebar>
    <router-view />
</div>
```

Use `<main-sidebar></main-sidebar>` not `<main-sidebar />`